# Auto-increment id when adding a feature to a PostGIS layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis

When I enter edit mode of a PostGIS layer in QGIS 1.8 and add a feature, is it possible to auto-increment the ID?

I always have to look what last used ID was and manually enter a new one. I can't believe I'm the first one facing this problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should do that on your table in postgres

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD COLUMN idcolumn BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY;
```

QGIS will auto increment that ID for you, well Postgres does and QGIS will just read it back once you save.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm creating my PostGIS tables with the QGIS plugin "PostGIS Manager". The clue was to choose the id column datatype as "BIGSERIAL" and not "INT". I had a primary key column wit integer data type before, but it works only with BIGSERIAL.